# How to scan documents by API in Node.js+react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an application written in Node.js+react, and search for an API that connects to a scanner and scans documents.
The only solution that I found is scanner.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/scanner-js) but it does not match my needs, because I want to do all the UI from my application, from the npm I want to get only the basic API:

1. Get a list of available scanners,
2. Start scan
3. Cancel scanning

Comment: There are some SDKs, but they are usually very costly. The only open-source option I know is this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-twain